# Battery pack for model B RPI, Thoughts?

Tags: power-supply, power, battery

Thinking of getting the battery pack linked to below for my model b Raspberry pi, i am wondering if anyone knows anything about it and how could it is because for first glance it looks amazing. Thanks guys

link: [http://www.amazon.com/12000mAh-External-Portable-Universal-Blackberry/dp/B008YRG5JQ/ref=pd_sim_cps_8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008YRG5JQ)

Comment: Looks amazing. I'm sure lots of people would like to know how long a RPi can (really) run off one of those.

Comment: Looks good. Specs say:
USB Output: 5V / 0.5A~2.1A
Max output: 3.5A

It has 4 ports, so say just over 1.5A per port you _could_ in theory run four Pis from it. If anything, I would say it's overkill for running one Pi. At a max of 3.5A There shouldn't be a problem running a Pi with various peripherals plugged into it.

Comment: Just had a look in the comments on the product and people _are_ using it to power a Raspberry Pi. One enterprising guy is even running the Pi, a wifi dongle and a Liliput screen off the battery. No word on how long it will last, but you've got to figure 9 hours at least for just running the Pi and a dongle off of it. Apparently you can also hot-charge it so you can charge it from the mains at the same time as running the Pi off of it. Very nice indeed.

Comment: @Raspberry_pi_eater Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please either mark the answer that solved it or create a self-answer with what you did and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**[Verified battery packs](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_external_Battery_packs_.28with_5.C2.A0V_regulated_output.29)** are already mentioned in the Wiki. Similar topic is covered by these links:

- http://www.element14.com/community/groups/raspberry-pi/blog/2012/09/01/portable-pi
- http://raspi.tv/tag/raspberry-pi-model-a-duration-test-on-2s-2000-mah-lipo
- http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2012/09/its-alive/
- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=11510
- http://www.instructables.com/id/MyLittlePwny-Make-a-self-powered-pentesting-box-/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this USB battery pack](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11360).

I found it when I was looking for an 10" LCD for my Raspberry.

- [Connexion 10" LCD LVDS bundle with capacitive touch screen and ambient light sensor](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/~/product/category=3094861&id=14647624)

It seems some people already tried it.

Comment: Please do not put Regards at end of question. People can see your avatar and name - They know you answered it with the best regards already :) Thank you for contributing = +1

Answer (score 1):

I got the USB battery pack mentioned above (EasyAcc 12000mAh External Battery Charger Pack)

When the pack is 100% loaded, my Pi runs about 13-15 hours (headless, w/o usb devices)

Comment: That's pretty darn good if you ask me!

Answer (score 0):

Battery packs are good, but when they're dead they don't let the Pi know. So the Pi dies and you risk SD card corruption. Anyone else remember SCANDISK or NTFSCHK? That, but worse.

The [MoPi](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/hamishcunningham/mopi-mobile-and-24-7-power-for-the-raspberry-pi?token=a93b16b7) board takes pretty much any battery and powers the Pi with it, without the risk of sudden cut-off. They get 8 to 10 hours on 8 Ni-Mh 2600 mAh AA rechargeable batteries.