# Diagnosing power supply issue

Tags: power-supply

I am running [LibreELEC 8.2.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801140442/https://libreelec.tv/2018/03/libreelec-krypton-8-2-4-mr/) on a RPi3B. I have attached a USB disk BUFFALO HD-PNTU3 (1To).

For the last week the disk has shown some issues which may be related to low power (making some noise while trying to access file from USB disk). I can also see the Lightning bolt symbol (⚡ in yellow) in top right screen of Kodi.

If I now ssh over to it I can see:

```
[ 7609.782469] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[11347.403707] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[11348.244208] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[11348.257137] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[11348.257158] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 5f 1f 60 00 00 08 00
[11348.257167] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6233952
[11348.257248] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[11348.257261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 5f 23 88 00 00 f0 00
[11348.257268] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 6235016
[11348.257278] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779369, lost async page write
[11348.257296] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779370, lost async page write
[11348.257306] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779371, lost async page write
[11348.257316] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779372, lost async page write
[11348.257325] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779373, lost async page write
[11348.257334] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779374, lost async page write
[11348.257344] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779375, lost async page write
[11348.257354] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779376, lost async page write
[11348.257364] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779377, lost async page write
[11348.257375] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 779378, lost async page write
[11352.280607] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
```

If I now unplug the external USB and check from my main laptop, I can check SMART is ok:

```
# smartctl -a -d sat /dev/sdc
...
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Could someone suggest tools/methodology to investiage possibly failing power supply ? I am using a cheap DSM-0525 from ebay:
[image: DSM-0525]

Which is supposed to power the RPI3b and the HD-PNTU3 :

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/
- http://www.buffalo-technology.com/products/storage-devices/portable-storage/ministationtm-portable-hard-drives/archive/ministation-plus/

The Power Supply is supposed to produce 2500mA output which seems to me should be plenty for both:

- [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply)

Comment: If you are seeing undervoltage indicators (the lightning bolt) there are really only two sources of the problem. The power supply and the cable.  To diagnose change the cable and retest. then do the same for the power supply.

Comment: ... and try a shorter cable first. 30-40cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try powering your RPi with the [thickest and shortest](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39066/usb-cables-why-are-some-of-them-bad-for-raspberry-pi) USB cable you can find. If that doesn't help, plug the HDD via a powered USB hub.

Comment: To be honest I was not convinced at all by your answer. But I found a very short USB cable and tried it. Et voilà ! It actually worked. Thanks very much for spreading the word, I was not searching for the right keywords.

Answer (score 0):

For later reference the original USB cable is 150 cm long and contains a OJ-313 switch:

[image]

The new short cable does not contains any switch anymore.